# Can't invoke MainActivity.super.onBackPressed() using DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a generic DialogFragment which I use in my MainActivity for several different usages. 
One of them is to show a confirmation dialog for exiting the app when the user presses the back button. If the user clicks 'yes', I want to call **MainActivity.super.onBackPressed()**. Problem is it doesn't work, it just dismiss the dialog. 
However, if I use **finish()** instead of MainActivity.super.onBackPressed() it works fine, but I've understood that the best practice would be to use super.onBackPressed() and not finish().
I've tried to use there just super.onBackPressed() or with getActivity(), doesn't resolve.

Any help is appreciated - how to properly invoke MainActivity.super.onBackPressed() from the DialogFragment?

This is my code:

```
public class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {
    // Do nothing by default
    private Runnable mConfirm = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };
    // Do nothing by default
    private Runnable mCancel = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };

    public void setArgs(String message, String yesButton, String noButton) {
        setArgs("", message, yesButton, noButton);
    }

    public void setArgs(String message, String yesButton) {
        setArgs("", message, yesButton, "");
    }

    public void setArgs(String title, String message, String yesButton, String noButton) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("message", message);
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("yes_button", yesButton);
        args.putString("no_button", noButton);
        setArguments(args);
    }

    public void setConfirm(Runnable confirm) {
        mConfirm = confirm;
    }

    public void setCancel(Runnable cancel) {
        mCancel = cancel;
    }

    @Override
    public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String message = getArguments().getString("message");
        String yesButton = getArguments().getString("yes_button");
        String noButton = getArguments().getString("no_button");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        if (!noButton.equals(""))
            builder.setNegativeButton(noButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mCancel.run();
                }
            });
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.my_launcher)
                .setTitle(title.equals("") ? res.getString(R.string.app_name) : title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(yesButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mConfirm.run();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        // If only positive button, center it.
        if (noButton.equals("")) {
            Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) positiveButton.getParent();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams positiveButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
            positiveButtonLL.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

And in my MainActivity:

```
public void showDialogFragment(DialogFragment newFragment) {
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction. We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    // save transaction to the back stack
    ft.addToBackStack("dialog");
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ConfirmationDialog dialog = new ConfirmationDialog();
    dialog.setArgs(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_app_msg), getResources().getString(R.string.yes), getResources().getString(R.string.no));
    Runnable confirm = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            **// finish();
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();**
        }
    };
    dialog.setConfirm(confirm);
    showDialogFragment(dialog);
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to close the app, right?

Comment: @miguelarc yes, this is what I'm tring to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your **`ConfirmationDialog`**

```
builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.my_launcher)
                .setTitle(title.equals("") ? res.getString(R.string.app_name) : title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(yesButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mConfirm.run();
                    }
                });
```

**or in your activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ConfirmationDialog dialog = new ConfirmationDialog();
    dialog.setArgs(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_app_msg), getResources().getString(R.string.yes), getResources().getString(R.string.no));
    Runnable confirm = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    };
    dialog.setConfirm(confirm);
    showDialogFragment(dialog);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first solution (modifying the ConfirmationDialog class) didn't work, dialog was dismissed but the app didn't exit. The second solution (modifying the activity) worked, but I needed to add "final" to "ConfirmationDialog dialog = new ConfirmationDialog()", not entirely sure why.

Comment: As we are accessing dialog object inside a run method, so that needs it to be final so it's value didn't get changed untill that code is executed

Answer (score 1):

Once your dialog is displayed, it gains the focus. Then your back press will just close the dialog and your activity gains focus again, with one more back press it will close your app if there is only one activity in activity stack. It's the normal flow.

If you want to exit your app:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(1);
```

or

```
// Recommended
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
startActivity(homeIntent);
```